# Azure Appservice with https

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

I turned *HTTPS Only* option on for my Spring application that I deployed to Azure App service. However, I still can make calls with http. It does not require/stop me using http. Any idea why?

```
http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/v4/callers/ping. // This perfectly works fine
```

Jdk11
spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Http only` options does not mean it will block the http requests. Instead, it will redirect the `http` requests to `https` request. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#enforce-https) for the details.

You can simple test this behavior by using the `develop tool` of the browser. For example, open a browswer(like chrome) -> press F12 button to open the `develop tool` -> input the url starts with `http://xxx` -> then check the traces in the develop tool -> you can see there're 2 traces, the first is for http, and the 2nd is for https. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your site is down.
Azure should automatically redirect your http req to https if you have set https_only:true.

You can verify this by looking at the "lock" icon at the start of your address bar.

Comment: http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/v4/callers/ping was just example. I did not put the real URL, if you tried to hit it.

Comment: Sweet. But did you check your browser and esure that the http request in NOT elevated to be https?